# Invalid operands to binary expression ('const char*' and 'const char *')

Tags: c++

I want to know the reason for this error in EASY words please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string exclam = "!";
    std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;

    std::cout << message << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> > test.cpp:55:35: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const char *' and 'const char *')
> >         std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;

Comment: Amazing eight-year old duplicate. Must be some silly online quiz site.

Comment: `"Hello"s + ", world"s + exclam;`

Comment: @M.M does not compile.  Am I missing something?  Using g++ and C++11

Comment: @blue_mango why not `std::string message = "Hello" ",world" + exclam;`?  Just drop the `+`

Comment: @BrunoEly you made a mistake somewhere,  obviously I cannot elaborate on that without seeing your code.  (NB. Don't post new questions in comments; post a new question)

Comment: @M.M it’s not a new question, it’s this question with your comment substituted in and the compiler doesn’t like the `s` appended to a string, complains I’m missing a semicolon between the string literal and the identifier.  So I wanted to know if there was something obvious I was missing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`"Hello"` and `", world"` aren't strings, they are `const char *` which as no overload for the `+` operator.

You would have to do something like this:

`std::string message = std::string("Hello") + std::string(", world") + exclam;`

Comment: More precisely they're arrays (i.e. `const char[]`), which could decay to pointers (i.e. `const char*`).

Comment: This was because that the '+' operator is left associative and the (string literal + string literal) would make a compilation error.